# How can I change the qualifier names of hbase table while importing it from mysql using Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

Mysql table -- Table name - companies_domains

```
company_id| company_name    | domain                                                                 
      1 | LITOFF          | LITOFF.IO  
      2 | HEWLETT PACKARD | HP.COM               
      3 | WORK DAY        | WORDAY.COM         
      4 | MADISON REED    | MR.COM
```

Hbase table -

```
hbase table name - company_domains
column family - company_details 
qualifiers name = com_na
                = dom

where
com_na = company_name
dom      = domain
```

here in sqoop command , we want to incrementally append the data from mysql  but I dont want the qualifiers name to be the same as in mysql . Please edit the below code as qualifiers name should be  com_name = company_name
dom      = domain

```
    sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://master.hadoop.local/emails --username root --password-file /user/hdfs/mysql_sqoop.password --table companies_domains --columns "company_id,company_name,domain" --hbase-table company_domains --column-family company_details --hbase-row-key company_id --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -m 2 --incremental append --check-column company_id --last-value 0
```